# What are some alternatives to the random surfer model in the Page Rank algorithm?

Tags: ranking, graph-theory

In the original PageRank algorithm, the authors introduced the idea of a random surfer,who was a user who while surfing the web, could either go from the current web page to a web page by clicking on one of the links in the current webpage, or opening a new tab and some random webpage. Speaking in terms of graphs, a random surfer could move from the current node to another node by  following one of the outgoing links from the current node, or could teleport with equal probability to any of the nodes in the graph. To this end, a teleportation or relaxation parameter "alpha" was introduced, which was the fraction of times a user would take the outgoing link from a node. The basic idea behind introducing teleportation was that if a node had only incoming links, it would "hoard" the pageRank of the other nodes. I wanted to know if there are any other alternatives to the random surfer approach, ie an approach where teleporation is not allowed, but still we are able to solve the problem of having nodes with no outgoing links, or disconnected graphs.

Comment: If the graph was connected, there are no dangling nodes, and there are no isolated web graphs, we can apply the classical PageRank model using the power method. The essence of the problem is that only particular graphs are able to converge using the power method, therefore we must make the adjacency matrix stochastic, irreducible, primitive using the random surfer. Beyond this, I feel you have to consider other algorithms and page rank will not work